# how to include a json decoded in a php file to another php file

Tags: php, json, include

hi i have a telegram api that it send a json code then i decode it and use it, but i want use this decode in another file to and cant set more than 1 at once so i try require or include but both doestn work
my main php code :

```
<?php
require 'functions.php';
//global $db;
//Bot
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");
$input=file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents('result.txt', $input.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
$update=json_decode($input,true);
$api_url="https://api.telegram.org/bot".API_TOKEN."/";`
```

then my secenod file i want to get decode on that to :

```
<?php
include '../main.php';
require_once '../main.php';
```

get json decoded thing in my second file to

Comment: Why are you using both `include` and `require_once` on the same file?

Comment: You should be able to use `$update` in the second file to access the decoded JSON.

Comment: make sure about file path may be that is your problem
may be it's include 'main.php'; or different path